# Display dropdown menu in gridview with autogeneratecolumns enabled

Tags: vb.net, gridview, drop-down-menu, sqldatasource, detailsview

I see a bunch of solutions about editing the template, but seeing as how my gridview changes between 10 different datasources a template isn't possible. Any idea of how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle the [OnRowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) event and populate the cell yourself?

Comment: Something like: e.Row.Cells(1).Controls.Clear()
then add the dropdown list and set it to the correct datasource?

Any idea how I can identify the cell by its name?

Comment: Is there a pattern that you can follow? If not then iterate throught the columns collection for the column of a particular name. Record the index and use that. Might want to cache the index for performance.

Comment: I also only want the dropdown list to display when editing, so is onrowdatabound the correct event?